# Abbreviation for ternary operator in python

Tags: python, conditional-operator

I seem to remember an abreviation for the ternary operator testing for existence.  For example:

```
a = None
b = a if a else 'Not None!'
# b is now 'Not None!'
```

I thought it was something like this

```
a else 'Not None!'
```

but that doesn't work.  Perhaps there is another way to abbreviate this using some other built-in type?

Comment: ^That should have been obvious.  Post as an answer?

Comment: It's worth noting they are *not* the same in some contexts (where the *else* case evaluates to `False`), and you should always use the ternary operator if that is what you actually want for readability. You see this mainly in old code, since the ternary operator wasn't in old versions of Python. Making something shorter doesn't make it better.

Comment: Maybe you were thinking of this: `cond and x or y`

Comment: Well, the shorthand some people like that relies on short circuit logic and falsiness is `a or 'Not None!'`.  I'm not a fan though.

Comment: @Lattyware - I can't reproduce the case you are worried about. Can you give an explicit example?

Comment: Abbreviate a ternary operator? Soo meta :D

Comment: @Robᵩ Sorry, I didn't think too carefully - in `cond and x or y`, if `x` evaluates to `False`, it won't work as with the ternary operator. Where `cond` and `x` are the same, as in your case, this isn't a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, there is no abbreviation available.

Were you thinking about `a or 'Not None!'` instead?

And as a side note: `... if ... else ...` is called an [conditional expression](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions); it is **a** ternary operator, but so is the SQL `BETWEEN ... IN ...` expression.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in your case there is an abbreviation.

```
b = a or 'Not None!'
```

is nearly equivalent to

```
b = a if a else 'Not None!'
```

The only difference is that `a` is evaluated once in the first case, and twice in the second. The value placed into `b` is the same in either case.

Also, realize that in either code, you may get unexpected results if `a` is not None, but still False-y. Consider what happens if `a` is `0.0`, for example.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't really make sense to me

```
a = None
b = a if a else 'Not None!'
```

You're setting b to `Not None!` for any false value of `a` (including `None`)

Perhaps you were thinking

```
a = None
b = 'Not None!' if a is None else a
```

or something?

Anyway, except for the cases where you can get away with

```
b = a or 'Not None!'
```

or

```
b = a and 'Not None!'
```

There's no way to avoid mentioning `a` twice